# Firebase android onAuthStateChanged not fired and result code is -1 always

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a signing activity and I am using Firebase auth and firebase UI for my app. I have two buttons on my login screen Google + and another for email password combination.

I have two problems

My Auth state changed is not firing and in my onActivityResult my result code is always -1

When I close my app and re-install/re-run my app, I am taken to a blank screen.

Please see signinactivity below

```
public class SigninActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private static final String TAG = "SigninActivity";

//private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

private String mUsername, loginUser;

// Firebase instance variables
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage;
private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;
private StorageReference mChatPhotosStorageReference;
private View mLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    // Initialize Firebase components
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    // Initialize references to views
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    // Initialize progress bar
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();;
            Log.d("onAuthStateChanged", String.valueOf(user));
            if (user != null) {
                if (user.getDisplayName() != null) {
                    loginUser = onSignedInInitialize(user.getDisplayName());
                } else {
                    loginUser = onSignedInInitialize(getString(R.string.email_user));
                }
                // User is signed in
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setProviders(
                                        AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                                        AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                                .setTheme(R.style.GreenTheme)
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
        mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Log.d("requestCode", String.valueOf(requestCode));
        Log.d("resultCode", String.valueOf(resultCode));
        Log.d("data", String.valueOf(data));

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Sign-in succeeded, set up the UI
            Snackbar.make(mLayout, getString(R.string.signin_string),
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Sign in was canceled by the user, finish the activity
            Snackbar.make(mLayout, getString(R.string.signin_cancel),
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.sign_out_menu:
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private String onSignedInInitialize(String username) {
    if (username != null) {
        mUsername = username;
    } else {
        mUsername = getString(R.string.email_sign);
    }
    return username;
}
}
```

trace:

I tried debugging my code and requestCode is 1 (as expected, but the result code is -1)

02-11 10:34:19.609 4429-4429/App_Name D/requestCode:1

02-11 10:34:19.609 4429-4429/App_Name D/resultCode:-1

Comment: Your trace shows `resultCode` is -1.  That value is [Activity.RESULT_OK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK).  That means your invocation of `AuthUI` with `requestCode` of `RC_SIGN_IN` (equals 1) succeeded.  The occurrence of that activity result also means your `AuthStateListener` is firing, because that is where you invoke `AuthUI`.  Can you explain further what the problem is?

Comment: The issue is, when I close my app (close in background without sign out) and open my app, I get a blank screen

Comment: Note that a successful sign-in is retained on the device until the user signs-out.  It looks like if `SigninActivity` is started when the user is already signed-in, it  calls `onSignedInInitialize()` and then does _not_ `finish()`.  Is that possibly the blank sceen you are seeing?

Comment: This answered the question and the blank screen was due to finish. I used standard FLAGS before starting the activity and it helped resolve the issue

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Response from qbix helped resolve my issue

Comment: Solution or explanation should be provided.